# Best way to establish local database online for payment application integration

Tags: sql, azure, architecture, pos

A client I am working for needs their data accessible online. I need to be able to from my own API and application service running on the web write PUTS and do GETS from the existing database. They are running an SQL Server, so I am thinking just making this accessible online.

would it be best to run a complete Azure copy SQL relational database? they are currently running Swiftpos. or should I run a CosmosDB database?

For starting out I am thinking that an Azure Cloud database would be best purely for handling traffic.
whenever a product gets updated in the database I would need to capture this and push it to the cloud database.

Comment: It's about business processes, requirements and consulting, not programming or coding, so off-topic on this site?

Comment: Hi @Mitch Storrie, If my answer is helpful for you, hope you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could think about using Azure SQL database, it has the feature: [Data Sync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/sql-data-sync-data-sql-server-sql-database) which seams meet your request.

Data Sync is useful in cases where data needs to be kept updated across several databases in Azure SQL Database or SQL Server. Here are the main use cases for Data Sync:

- **Hybrid Data Synchronization:** With Data Sync, you can keep data
  synchronized between your databases in SQL Server and Azure SQL
  Database to enable hybrid applications. This capability may appeal to
  customers who are considering moving to the cloud and would like to
  put some of their application in Azure.
- **Distributed Applications:** In many cases, it's beneficial to separate
  different workloads across different databases. For example, if you
  have a large production database, but you also need to run a
  reporting or analytics workload on this data, it's helpful to have a
  second database for this additional workload. This approach minimizes
  the performance impact on your production workload. You can use Data
  Sync to keep these two databases synchronized.
- **Globally Distributed Applications:** Many businesses span several
  regions and even several countries/regions. To minimize network
  latency, it's best to have your data in a region close to you. With
  Data Sync, you can easily keep databases in regions around the world
  synchronized.

You can sync the data from local to cloud or cloud to local. And data will be synced every 5 min. You also could manually set it.

Before you configure Date Sync, you should firstly migrate your database to Azure. The easiest way it using SSMS: [Deploy Database to Microsoft Azure SQL Database](https://developer.relatude.com/deploying-a-sql-database-to-azure-with-sql-server-management-studio).

HTH.